# PM2 return Error 'spawn ps' on restart with watch option

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have a small app in nodejs that I would run with **PM2**.
PM2 should restart when my script change.

And it seems works but, **when PM2 restart the app after changed** if I check my pm2 logs **I see this error**.
I can't figure out where the error can be, because seems a PM2 error.

```
PM2         | Change detected on path src/discover.js for app discover - restarting
PM2         | Stopping app:discover id:0
PM2         | { Error: spawn ps ENOENT
PM2         |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
PM2         |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
PM2         |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
PM2         |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
PM2         |   errno: 'ENOENT',
PM2         |   code: 'ENOENT',
PM2         |   syscall: 'spawn ps',
PM2         |   path: 'ps',
PM2         |   spawnargs: [ '-o', 'pid', '--no-headers', '--ppid', 15 ] }
PM2         | App [discover:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2         | pid=15 msg=process killed
PM2         | App [discover:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2         | App [discover:0] online
```